# Relative bounds for vorticity

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations, elliptic-pde, numerical-analysis-of-pde

Write the vorticity equation as

\begin{equation}\label{Eq20}
\begin{split}
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t} v_i &  = \biggl[|\textbf{v}|~|\nabla u_i|\cos(\beta_i)- |\textbf{u}|~|\nabla v_i|\cos(\alpha_i)\biggr]+  \nu \bigtriangleup v_i\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

with $\alpha_i$ as the angle between $\textbf{v}$ and $\nabla u_i$, and $\beta_i$ the angle between the vectors $\textbf{u}$ and $\nabla v_i$. Take any mapping $$\varphi:\mathbb{R}^3\times \mathbb{R}^3\times \mathbb{R}^3\times \mathbb{R}^3\times [0,\infty)\rightarrow  \mathbb{R}^3\times [0,\infty)$$ such that $$\varphi(\textbf{f},\textbf{g}, \nabla f_i, \nabla g_i)\ge \biggl[|\textbf{f}|~|\nabla g_i|\cos(\lambda_i)- |\textbf{g}|~|\nabla f_i|\cos(\eta_i)\biggr]$$ for any smooth vector fields $\textbf{f}$ and $\textbf{g}$ with $\lambda_i$ as the angle between $\textbf{f}$ and $\nabla g_i$, and $\eta_i$ the angle between the vectors $\textbf{g}$ and $\nabla f_i$. Consider any solution $\xi =[\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3]$ to the PDE

$$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\xi_i = \varphi(\xi, \textbf{curl}(\xi), \nabla \xi_i, \nabla (\textbf{curl}(\xi))_i   )+\nu \bigtriangleup \xi_i$$

Is it true that $$\dfrac{\partial }{\partial t} v_i(x,t)\le   \dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\xi_i(x,t)$$ whenever $\xi(x,0) = \textbf{v}(x,0)$?

Comment: Hi there! I would recommend to format your actual question so that it stands out more. Either by removing the text after it; or else by at least clearly delineating that.

Comment: @MaxHorn sorry the question is so long because I just wanted to show the work involved. I'll try to shorten it or bolden the question